# Get audio samples from audio element

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, html5-audio, webrtc

I want to get live audio from a microphone using web browser and send it to a Node.js server via websockets. I am using BinaryJS library to send binary data to the server. I am having problem in getting the audio samples from the microphone. Here is what I have:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var context = new AudioContext();
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true}, function(micstream){

    audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(micstream);

    }, errorCallback);

});

var errorCallback = function(e){
    console.log("Rejected!", e);
};
```

I want some way to get the audio sample at every 10ms or so so that I can write it to the websocket stream. I am looking for something like this:

```
function getSample(){
    //read the current data in byte buffer.

    setTimeout(getSample, 10);
}
```

Can someone tell me how to do this? Or is there another way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: This may help you: http://typedarray.org/from-microphone-to-wav-with-getusermedia-and-web-audio/

Comment: I saw this post earlier. The problem is this code is converting the data to a wav file locally. What I want to achieve is to pipe the microphone audio directly to the websocket server.

Comment: Just skip the converting to wav and push the data directly to your web socket connection ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Recorderjs or the MediaStream Recording API (implemented in Firefox Nightly, Intent to Implement for Chrome): http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html; http://simpl.info/mr

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware I tried pushing it to the server. Reassemble it on server and create the wav file from that. But I get errors about unreadable stream data. I am trying to fix that.

Comment: When you createObjectURL it will have some extra stuff not just your audio data. So you need to find a way to convert audio stream in to pure binary, and not ObjectURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These points should get you on the right track:

- You want to send the data raw, so create a `JavaScriptNode` or `ScriptProcessor` from your context and utilize the `onaudioprocess` for your function. You can easily set your time intervals to make sure it is only every 10ms. This is very similar to what the current RTCRecorders do.
- The packets that are create by default are `float PCM`. You COULD convert them to `16 bit PCM` in JavaScript but media libraries worth their weight(I know for sure Gstreamer) could translate the stream.

Here is [code that I wrote](https://github.com/Computician/WebSocketWebRTCRecorders). This code is just modified versions of the recorders that already exist but I send the data over a websocket and I do not modify it in javascript but the function to change from float to 16bit PCM audio is included in the source code if you need it. You could pop a time check in the `onaudioprocess` and move the `websocket` out of the `worker`(only Chrome supports WebSockets in Worker threads currently) and you should be good to go.